# LibGDX: Cannot destory screen. Memory leaks

Tags: java, memory-leaks, libgdx

I have a problem with my LibGDX game. Memory leaks occur when switching between screens. Here is a part of my main class extending `Game`. I use this class to switch between screens.

```
private LoadingScreen loadingScreen;
private Screen s = null;

public static enum Screens
{
    MAIN, START_SCREEN, CASUAL_LEVEL, NORMAL_LEVEL, HARDCORE_LEVEL, CREDITS,
}

@Override
public void create()
{
    s = new LoadingScreen(this);

    setScreen(s);
}

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
public void gotoScreen(Screens screen)
{
    s.dispose();
    s = null;

    if (screen == screen.MAIN)
    {
        s = new Main(this);
    }

    if (screen == screen.START_SCREEN)
    {
        s = new StartScreen(this);
    }

    if (screen == screen.CASUAL_LEVEL)
    {
        s = new CasualLevel(this);
    }

    if (screen == screen.NORMAL_LEVEL)
    {
        s = new NormalLevel(this);
    }

    if (screen == screen.HARDCORE_LEVEL)
    {
        s = new HardcoreLevel(this);
    }

    if (screen == screen.CREDITS)
    {
        s = new Credits(this);
    }

    super.setScreen(s);
}
```

As you can see, I am passing in `this` class to each of my screens so that I can switch between screens from inside them. I am also setting the old screen to `null` which should basically destroy it and kick out of the memory.

The problem occurs when I leave a screen and then try to recreate it from scratch later on. It is not recreating it, but magically restoring the one I closed before.

All items on the screen from its previous instance are still there. Also, each time I switch the screen, the memory usage increases. E.g. if I go from the startscreen to casual, then back to startscreen, and then again to casual, the memory usage doubles.

I tried to google it for hours now, I seen people having exactly the same problem with libgdx, but no one seems to know the answer.

So in short, how to completely kill a screen so that it will get recreated from scratch next time I try to initialise it?

I've already tried calling `this.finalize()` and `System.gc()` after `s = null`, but it is not working. The memory usage keeps growing.

Comment: Can you post the entire code for one of those screens (one that you know is leaking memory)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code a bit

```
public void gotoScreen(Screens screen)
{
    System.gc();
    if (screen == screen.MAIN)
    {
        super.setScreen(new Main(this));
    }

    if (screen == screen.START_SCREEN)
    {
        super.setScreen(new StartScreen(this));
    }

    if (screen == screen.CASUAL_LEVEL)
    {
        super.setScreen(new CasualLevel(this));
    }

    if (screen == screen.NORMAL_LEVEL)
    {
        super.setScreen(new NormalLevel(this));
    }

    if (screen == screen.HARDCORE_LEVEL)
    {
        super.setScreen(new HardcoreLevel(this));
    }

    if (screen == screen.CREDITS)
    {
        super.setScreen(new Credits(this));
    }
}
```

And now, using VisualVM, I can see that the instances of Screens are being removed when switching between the screens.